# Storing a list or dictionary locally and accessing it all the time (.net/C#)

Tags: c#, .net, queue, storing-data

**What is the "problem"?**

We have a system in which data comes in (from scanning barcodes) and this data has to be moved into a database.
Simple enough.
The "problem" is the availability of the database, which is not 100% given (factors which we cannot solve, so we have to work around).

**Current solution:**

We have a pretty old software (with a language nobody knows anymore) here where it was solved like in the following solution.
The software gets the data within one thread T1 and writes it into a local file.
Another thread T2 reads this file periodically (~100ms), extracts the last input data and tries to push it into the database. Kinda like a message-queue. If the database is available, thread T2 will delete the data from the local file. If it is not available the data will stay in the file.
So, as long as the database is not available the data will accumulate within the file.
Why the file? Because the data will not be lost if the system has to be restarted (either planned or unplanned).

Obviously i could go the route of a simple database on the system itself, but that would just lead to more setup-time whenever we need to implement that solution somewhere.
So we would like to have a simple solution that needs no setup besides the application itself.

What would be some good solutions in this case?

Comment: Where does sorting come into this?

Comment: I recommend using a SQLite database for this problem. No need for installing any database engine, easy database access in C# and also solves the problem unplanned restarts

Comment: Using a simple local database such as [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/) or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) shouldn't impact setup. Both those just need a DLL that's copied into your application folder. (I personally am a fan of LiteDB.)

Comment: Instead of reading data from the file periodically, I'd read it directly from memory (and just load the file in memory at startup). I'd also only append data in the file, and delete the whole file when all data has been correctly sent to your DB.

Comment: As pointed out. Use SQLite - a simple interface in C# especially with POCO NuGet package- no additional runtime required other than your application. Use that for persistent storage - remove records once they've been successfully transferred. Common scenario on mobile platforms.